# Why isn't my sessions variable not working?

Tags: php, session

I wrote a piece of code to prevent anti spam on my website comments using the sessions superglobal however the variables I've assigned to them don't seem to be saving.

In    `sessions.php`    I've declared the session variables and although I haven't written it here `session_start ();` is at the top of `index.php`.

For clarification, here is the code :

sessions.php

```
      $numA= rand(0,10);
      $numB= rand(0,10);
      $sum= $numA + $numB;  
   
      $_SESSION['numA']=$numA;
      $_SESSION['numB']= $numB;
      $_SESSION['sum']= $sum= $numA + $numB;
```

index.php

```
      <div>
      <label for="security"><?php echo($_SESSION['numA'].'+'.$_SESSION['numB']) ;?> = </label>
      <input type="text" name="security" rows="5">
      </div>
```

What do you think the issue is?

Comment: How is `sessions.php` being included in `index.php`?

Comment: Check your log for "Headers already sent" warnings and fix it if you find it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas if I include the it in ```index.php``` some of the code I wrote there will interfere with the page

Comment: @Barmar how do I check for those warnings?

Comment: Depends on how your server is configured. Reviewing logs should be a normal part of development.

Comment: @Agent21, so, how is that code executed in the first place? Do they manually hit `sessions.php` and then you redirect them over to `index.php`?

Comment: Try add `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top. (see https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php for details)